# Content-Type header is being removed while accessing a REST service via SAP CPI

Tags: sap-cpi

I am trying to invoke a REST API via an SAP CPI iFlow. However the API fails with an error that the Content-Type Header is missing.
I have added a Content-Modifier and added Content-Type as a header, but it seems that the content-type is getting stripped off.

Any suggestions?